# Running multiple instances of Cassandra on a single machine by aliasing the IP address?

Tags: macos, cassandra, ip, alias

Looking at the configuration for Cassandra I can see that nodes are distinguished by IP address in `/apache-cassandra-2.0.3/conf/cassandra.yaml`.

```
cluster_name: ‘VirtualBox Cluster’
initial_token: 0
seed_provider:
- seeds:  "192.168.56.2"
listen_address: 192.168.56.2
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch
```

I'd like to run multiple nodes on my MacOSX Mavericks machine (without spinning up virtual machines)

My question is: **Will it work for me to distinguish multiple nodes by creating an IP address alias using `ifconfig`?** eg

```
sudo ifconfig en0 alias 192.168.0.101 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that yes this is possible, but you may prefer using CCM as a management tool for testing without VM's. In the repo readme it shows aliasing various IP's to 127.0.0.1 for setting up multiple cass instances on one machine.

```
- ccm works on localhost only for now. So if you want to create more than one
  node clusters the simplest way is to use multiple loopback aliases. On
  modern linux distribution you will probably have nothing to do, but
  on mac os x, you would have to create such aliases with
    sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up
    sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3 up
```

https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm

Comment: Thanks - just so I know - ccm works by setting each of the instances to have the same IP address but different ports? (Here https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm/blob/c553f62e3afc95323808e383a49dca09638aa0b4/ccmlib/node.py#L776) and (here http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/configuration/node_configuration#storage-port) Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, It's will associate a different data dir and Cassandra instance with each port, it's pretty great for just trying out a cluster setup on a single machine.